# How to improve this hash function

Tags: r, hash

Is there anyway to improve the speed of the initalization of this hash?
Currently this takes around 20 minutes on my machine.

```
#prepare hash()
hash <- list();

mappedV <- # matrix with more than 200,000 elements
for( i in 1:nrow(mappedV) ) {
  hash[[paste(mappedV[i,], collapse = '.')]] <- 0;
}
```

Before this piece of code, I used a matrix, but this took me more than 3 hours. So I wont complain about the 20 minutes. I am just curious if there are better alternatives. I use the hash function to count each of the 200,000 possible combination.

PS: To concurrency is maybe one option. But this doesn't improve the hashing.

Comment: I suspect you could use an environment look up or data.table here but to me it's not clear what you're trying to do big picture with this.  Perhaps actually running through this with a small sample data set and your expected results will yield better responses from SO suers.

Comment: I used the very slow approach to solve some homework I got a few years ago. We had to count ceratain combination in a very large matrix. And last week I just stumbled over it and was just curios if there is a faster way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also you an `environment` as a hash ... let's see:

```
mappedV <- matrix(1:100000, ncol=5)
hash1 <- list()
hash2 <- new.env(hash=TRUE)

system.time(for(i in 1:nrow(mappedV)) hash1[[paste(mappedV[i,], collapse = '.')]] <- 0)
#   user  system elapsed 
# 19.263   1.321  21.634 

system.time(for(i in 1:nrow(mappedV)) hash2[[paste(mappedV[i,], collapse = '.')]] <- 0)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.426   0.002   0.430
```

### Updated to answer "things to be aware of"

As Josh O'Brien pointed out, this is so fast because the entire environment isn't copied when modified. Seems useful, right?

"Problems" can arise when you expect these objects to behave like most other objects you are used to with respect to its immutability. When the `environment` is modified somewhere, it makes changes to it everywhere. For instance, if we pass the `environment` into a function that deletes all of its elements, the `environment` will get hosed everywhere, whereas the list won't.

Witness:

```
hash1 <- list(a=1:10, b=rnorm(10))
hash2 <- new.env(hash=TRUE)
hash2$a <- 1:10
hash2$b <- rnorm(10)

danger <- function(x, axe) {
  for (wut in axe) x[[wut]] <- NULL
}

## the list is safe
danger(hash1, names(hash1))
hash1
# $a
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
#
# $b
# [1] -0.8575287  0.5248522  0.6957204 -0.7116208
# [2]  0.5536749  0.9860218 -1.2598799 -1.1054205
# [3]  0.3472648

## The environment gets mutilated
danger(hash2, names(hash1))
as.list(hash2)
# $a
# NULL
# 
# $b
# NULL
```

Comment: wow this is fast, now it took less than a minute. Why is it so much faster?

Comment: @Christian -- Because the entire environment is not copied each time a new object is added to it (whereas when adding to a list, it is).

Comment: @Josh O'Brien -- are there any site effects I have to be aware of?

Comment: @Christian: I updated my answer with an example of something to look out for wrt environments and immutability. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thx to you all. This is a great answer.

Answer (score 5):

You'll often save significant time by pre-allocating a list of the desired length, rather than growing it at each iteration.

Behold:

```
X <- vector(mode="list", 1e5)
Y <- list()

system.time(for(i in 1:1e5) X[[i]] <- 0)
#    user  system elapsed 
#     0.3     0.0     0.3 
system.time(for(i in 1:1e5) Y[[i]] <- 0)
#    user  system elapsed 
#   48.84    0.05   49.34 
identical(X,Y)
# [1] TRUE
```

Because the entire list `Y` gets copied each time it's added to, appending additional elements only gets slower and slower as it grows in size.

Comment: Of course..yes pre-allocating is the way ..but here the OP looks he tries to assign the names of a list .. here your code is equivalent to `X[] <- 0` and I think is faster ..

Answer (score 2):

It's not as fast as using an environment, but there's a straightforward vectorised solution to the problem:

```
mappedV <- matrix(1:100000, ncol = 5)
hashes <- apply(mappedV, 1, paste, collapse = ".")

hash <- list()
hash[hashes] <- 0
```

Or of course you could just turn a vector of 0's into list and name it:

```
hash <- as.list(rep(0, length = length(hashes)))
names(hash) <- hashes
```

That takes <0.001s on my computer.